# Amazon MWS is there REST version API?

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-mws

I have client which is interested to build product based on Amazon MWS API , but one which I found is actually XML. I use to work in REST JSON formats - is there any alternative? Is there any of Beta version? for example here https://www.programmableweb.com/api/amazon-marketplace-web-service I can see architecture style REST - but its xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MWS API only returns XML as far as I know. Assuming you want to process it with Node (since you've tagged the question node.js), you can use the package [`xml2js`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) to convert the xml to a JS object which is easily made JSON with `JSON.stringify()`.